# slickgrid columns gets shrinked

Tags: slickgrid

I have two main tabs named `A` and `B`. Under `A` I have three more tabs, and each have `slickgrid`. Under the `B` tab I have two more tabs, each with `slickgrid`.

All of the columns of `A`'s slickgrid are shrunk and stay left in the following scenario:

- Data is loading in a subtab of `A`
- User switches to `B`
- User returns to `A` after the data is loaded

Each column has a size around 10px in this shrunken state and is causing a lot of problems. How can I fix this?

Comment: Typically it's appropriate to include the relevant code, if you can provide a concise snippet. This will allow us to see where things might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Call `grid.resizeCanvas()` after the tab has been activated/shown. If you are doing any kind of animation when switching between tabs then you need to make sure to call `grid.resizeCanvas()` **after** the animation has finished.